# Files in Google Shared Drive not sending push notifications

Tags: google-api, webhooks

I have been able to successfully create and receive webhook events for files in my personal drive, how ever when I try to set them up for a file in a shared drive I receive no events.

I get a status 200 when creating the webhook. So it seems that the webhook for file in the shared drive is being created properly. But after the initial 200 response no events follow no matter which changes to the file are made.

below is the request I have been using.

Perhaps this is a permissions issues but I can't find anything in Google's documentation on how to support push notifications in shared drives.

````
          request({
            method: 'POST',
            uri:`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}`,
            json: true,
            body: {
              id: '',
              type: 'web_hook',
              address: ``,
              expiration: expiration_date,
            },
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer` },
            qs: {
              includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
              supportsAllDrives: true,
              supportsTeamDrives: true,
            },
          }),
    ```

Thanks
````